# Is this (simple) for loop doing what I want it to?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have pretty much no experience with cygwin & UNIX but need to use it for extracting a large set of data from a even larger set of files... 
I had some help yesterday to do this short script, but (after running for ~7-8 hours) the script simply wrote to the same output file 22 times. Atleast that's what I think happened.

I've now changed the code to this (see below) but it would be really awesome if someone who knows how this is done properly could tell me if it's likely to work before I waste another 8 hours...

```
for chr in {1..22}
do
zcat /cygdrive/g/data/really_long_filename$chr | sed '/^#/d' | cut -f1-3 >> db_to_rs_$chr
done
```

I want it to read file 1..22, remove rows starting with #, and send columns 1 to 3 to a file ending with the same number 1..22

yesterday the last part was just `...-f1-3 >> db_to_rs` which I suspect just rewrote that file 22 times?

Help is much appreciated
~L

Comment: You can also try running the code with `{1..3}` to waste only 1 hour. If it works well, you can then run the rest with `{4..22}`.

Comment: Haha that's actually a good idea, thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code would work as expected.

When the command ended in `...-f1-3 >> db_to_rs`, it essentially appended all the output to the file `db_to_rs`.

Saying `... >> db_to_rs_$chr` would create filenames ending in `{1 .. 22}`.

However, note that saying `>>` would *append* the output to a file.  So if `db_to_rs1` already exists, the output would be *appended*.  If you want to create a *new* file instead, say `>` instead of `>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer !
But wait, so all data was there in the output yesterday, just appended at the end ? When I checked it, it only contained data from one of the input files. I think atleast, I should recheck that maybe?

Comment: If the output files doesn't already exists (they don't) will '>>' create them? In this case '>' is better?

Comment: If the output file doesn't exist, `>>` will create those.  If those exist, output will be appended if you use `>>`.  If you want to create new files on every run, use `>`.